# Retrieving large records from an Oracle table takes more time

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table with 400,000 records, and the DATA_NAME and SEQU_ID fields has index. We have also rebuilt the index on that table today. However, executing the following query takes 2 to 3 minutes. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
Select distinct SEQU_ID,DATA_VALUE from DATA_MYSUBMISSION_DETAILS where DATA_NAME ='PLAN_ID';

Initializing connection...
Connection ready. Took 2.405 seconds.

Statement completed successfully. (21832 results). 2 minutes, 12 seconds. (Line 1).

Finished. Total time: 2 minutes, 15 seconds.
```

**Table structure** => DESC DATA_MYSUBMISSION_DETAILS

```
        Name              Null?    Type           
        ----------------- -------- -------------- 
        RECORD_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(34)   
        SEQU_ID           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(34)   
        DATA_NAME         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)  
        DATA_VALUE                 NVARCHAR2(512) 
        DATA_INDEX        NOT NULL NUMBER(18)     
        RELATED_RECORD_ID          VARCHAR2(34)   
        CREATED_BY                 VARCHAR2(34)   
        CREATED_TS                 TIMESTAMP(6)   
        MODIFIED_BY                VARCHAR2(34)   
        MODIFIED_TS                TIMESTAMP(6)
```

**INDEXS** => SELECT index_name FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = 'DATA_MYSUBMISSION_DETAILS';

```
    "INDEX_NAME"
    "IDXDATADETSEQID"
    "IDXDATADETPROPVAL"
    "INDXDATADETPROPNAME"
    "DATA_MYSUBMISSION_DETAILS_PK"
```

Comment: Can you include the current table indices in your question?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have added the column and idex details

Comment: (1) You are querying on `DATA_NAME`. Is this column the leading column in one of those indexes you listed (the index names are meaningless to us)? (2) the value `'PLAN_ID'` doesn't look very unique - I'm guessing that there's a significant percentage of the table with matching rows. if so, you *don't want to use an index*, and if Oracle *is* using an index, that will actually slow you down. You need to examine the execution plan and based on your knowledge of the cardinality of your predicate column decide whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: Plain_ID is not the unique.

Comment: @Sid Based on your column sizes and row counts, the table consumes less than 310 MB. No matter how Oracle is reading from that table - either full table scan or index - I can't imagine any modern database server needing 2 minutes to finish scanning all the rows to know which to return. What program are you using to read from the database? Is it reading the rows in batches, or is it reading them over a slow connection one-row-at-a-time?

Answer (score -1):

1. set autotrace trace explain

set autotrace trace explain;

--run your select

--check the plan using index or not.

--turn off autotrace

set autotrace off;
2. use dbms_session to trace the sql.

alter session set tracefile_identifier='xyz';

exec dbms_session.session_trace_enable();

--run your select

exec dbms_session.session_trace_disable();
3. tkprof

cd $ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace

tkprof *xyz.trc a.out

check a.out the details of timing.

## Example

```
HR@asp>set autotrace trace explain
```

**Only print the plan**

```
HR@asp>select * from employees where employee_id=100;
```

**run the test sql**

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1833546154

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------

| Id  | Operation                   | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU
)| Time     |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |               |     1 |    69 |     1   (0
)| 00:00:01 |

|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEES     |     1 |    69 |     1   (0
)| 00:00:01 |

|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | EMP_EMP_ID_PK |     1 |       |     0   (0
)| 00:00:01 |
```

**=> Index is used.**

```
HR@asp>set autotrace off;
```

**=>turn off autotrace.**

```
HR@asp>exec dbms_session.session_trace_enable();  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**=>enable session trace.**

```
HR@asp>alter session set tracefile_identifier='xyz'; 

Session altered.
```

**=>set identifier to find the trace file.**

```
HR@asp>select * from employees where employee_id=100; 

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------- -------------------------
EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE          JOB_ID
------------------------- -------------------- ------------------ ----------
    SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
---------- -------------- ---------- -------------
        100 Steven               King
SKING                     515.123.4567         17-JUN-03          AD_PRES
     24000                                      90
```

**=>run the test sql.**

```
HR@asp>exec dbms_session.session_trace_disable(); 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**=>turn off trace. the trace file is created in udump directory.**

```
[oracle@hol trace]$ ls -lt|grep xyz  **=> this is udump directory.**
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba      4068 Mar 28 19:25 asp_ora_30627_xyz.trc
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba        96 Mar 28 19:25 asp_ora_30627_xyz.trm
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba      5612 Mar 28 19:14 asp_ora_29418_xyz.trc
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba       162 Mar 28 19:14 asp_ora_29418_xyz.trm
[oracle@hol trace]$ tkprof asp_ora_30627_xyz.trc c.out
```

**=> analyze the trc file and create a report named c.out. which includes timing information you need.**

```
[oracle@hol trace]$ ls -l c.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 6623 Mar 28 19:26 c.out
```

**=>the report file.**

Comment: While this may possibly answer the question (although I don't think it does) it is a wall of commands with zero explanation of why they are relevant to the OP's question and no explanation of what actions the OP should take based on this output. Please [edit] your answer and provide a coherent explanation of why these commands should be used and how the output allows the OP to solve their problem.